# Sorting date in string format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I got this list of date array that I am trying to sort:

```
var arr = ['2017/12/16', 
'2017/05/01',
'2017/04/20',
'2017/03/10',
'2017/08/12',
'2017/03/06',
'2017/02/04',
'2017/01/07',
'2016/02/08',
'2015'09/08'];
```

They are in yyyy/mm/dd format. I tried to use this function to sort:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
 a = a.split('/').reverse().join('');
  b = b.split('/').reverse().join('');
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
});
```

However, it tells me that a.split is not a function.

Comment: You realize you have a typo in the last date, it's `'2015/09/08'`, while it should be `'2015/09/08'` after replacing the inner quotation with a slash.

Comment: Why do you try convert the date? Just use `var sorted = arr.sort();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of split/reverse/join just convert the string to `Date` object and let javascript do the sorting for you:

```js
var arr = ['2017/12/16', 
'2017/05/01',
'2017/04/20',
'2017/03/10',
'2017/08/12',
'2017/03/06',
'2017/02/04',
'2017/01/07',
'2016/02/08',
'2015/09/08'
];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  da = new Date(a);
  db = new Date(b);
  if (da == db) {
    return 0;
  }
  return da > db ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: But strangely my result sorted in descending order

Comment: Nope it does not work. No matter I changed the < or > sign, it is still printing the original unsorted array

Comment: Without looking at your code that you use it will be a bit hard to help :)

Comment: Ah I figured out why is it so already. Because my array was an object array so I needed to do a.date and b.date. Thanks!!!

Comment: A few issues with this snipptet, 1) "parsing of date strings with the Date constructor... is strongly discouraged" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), 2)`da > db` is not correct in a sort callback and 3) conversions are simply not needed in this case (see below)

Comment: @georg thanks for the comment, the `da > db` - changed to 1/-1.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to convert the strings in your array, you can simply compare strings by using the default behavior of [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var arr = [
    '2017/12/16',
    '2017/05/01',
    '2017/04/20',
    '2017/03/10',
    '2017/08/12',
    '2017/03/06',
    '2017/02/04',
    '2017/01/07',
    '2016/02/08',
    '2015/09/08'
];

arr.sort();

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Why do you use callback for `sort` function? `arr.sort()` is enough.

Comment: @PatrickHund Nope it does not work, it is still printing the unsorted array

Comment: Did you fix the syntax error in your code? The last date string in the input array has a single quote char in it that doesn't belong there. You can see that my code example works simply by hitting the “Run code snippet” button

Comment: btw, sort sorts the given array in situ.

Comment: @PatrickHund note that `sort` works inplace, you don't need to create a new variable for that.